# What does "long since shed" mean?

Tags: word-usage, literature

I am reading Star Wars Episode I. One sentence goes like this:

"His smooth, boyish face suggested an immaturity that had been long since shed."

I am not sure what the phrase "long since shed" means. It would be great if anyone can help me out. My guess is, it would take a long time for him to grow out of immaturity, so he is very young ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does the dictionary tell about the verb *shed*?

Answer (score 1):

One definition of "shed" [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shed) is:

> to cast off some natural covering (as fur or skin): the cat is shedding

His face is boyish; but he has shed his immaturity.  His immaturity is what has been shed "long since"--that is, a long time ago (but not too long, since he still looks boyish looking). So he is young but mature.

A person can shed a bad habit (get rid of it); but the definition here uses the idea that the shedding is an involuntary act, like a cat shedding fur or a snake shedding skin.

Comment: Thx. I think I was distracted by the phrase 'long since.'  Now it completely makes sense.